# SQL Server Management Studio with Multi subnet HADR cluster

Tags: ssms, availability-groups, hadr

We are starting to deploy Multi-Subnet HADR AlwaysOn clusters for our environment. Using `MultiSubnetFailover=True` in application connection strings works.

However, SSMS connections require manual paste of this connection parameter into the additional connection parameters window for every connection.

Is there a workaround to automatically add this for all connections?

Alternately, using a Central Management Server to store connections for multiple SQL Servers, is there a way to store this here?

Thanks.
Jeremy

Comment: [The SSMS 'Connect to Server' dialog does not persist the settings specified in the 'Additional Connection Parameters' tab](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/813973/the-ssms-connect-to-server-dialog-does-not-persist-the-settings-specified-in-the-additional-connection-parameters-tab#tabs) is closed as **Wont Fix**. You can use SSMS addin - [SSMS Boost](http://www.ssmsboost.com/) - ["Preferred connections" and specify "Additional connection parameters"](http://serverfault.com/a/625599). Else you have to manually paste it for every connection - thats buggy SSMS :-(

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/786323/ssms-sql-server-management-studio-2012-missing-connection-properties-for-availability-groups more accurately describes issue and is OPEN.

Comment: Jeremy, the above Microsoft link status is now closed but the solution still does not work :-(